# htaccess redirect with on rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, rule

how to write one rule what would satisfy all this redirect what I try to achive with the following rules

```
RewriteRule ^desktop/page/1/ /tag/desktop/page/1/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^desktop/page/2/ /tag/desktop/page/2/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^desktop/page/3/ /tag/desktop/page/3/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^desktop /tag/desktop [R,L]
```

the last one is never executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^desktop(/.*)?$ /tag/desktop$1 [R,L]
```

Or if you must limit it to page/number:

```
RewriteRule ^desktop(/(page/[0-9]+/?)?)?$ /tag/desktop$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: thanks a lo. Just on thing in this case the redirects to pages is not working, everything is getting redirected to /desktop. Is there a way to get it work for pages as well?

Comment: @user1659575 With that rule in a blank htaccess file, and I enter `http://localhost/desktop/page/1/` in my browser, I get redirected to `http://localhost/tag/desktop/page/1/`.