# Special .htaccess redirect rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686839/htaccess-redirect-with-on-rule) and got that working perfectly. I was all happy and stuff, and then tried to solve my problem again, after which I realised that I have no freakin clue what I'm doing.

I need to redirect users from this url:

```
www.domain1.com/username/faxtoemail.php
```

To this url:

```
www.domain2.com/reseller/username
```

Where username is the reseller's username. So that username will be different for each user but the same on both domains.

I was thinking that it might be possible to match it on faxtoemail.php (this file won't exist anywhere else in the site as that site is being moved to a wordpress install). Also, there's about 11tybillion of them, so changing all the php files to redirect will be tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/faxtoemail\.php$ /reseller/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Just before you posted this answer I came up with this: `RewriteRule ^domain1.com(/.*/)faxtoemail.php?$ domain2.com/reseller$1 [R,L]` Yours looks better though. EDIT: It doesn't work though. Doesn't redirect.

Comment: You mean `RewriteRule ^domain1.com(/.*/)faxtoemail.php?$ domain2.com/reseller$1 [R,L]` is working fine? That cannot work since `RewriteRule` only matches request URI.

Comment: What do you mean it only matches request URI?

Comment: Take `http://domain.com/foo/bar?a=1` for example. `RewriteRule` matches only `foo/bar` from that URL.

Comment: No worries, I see what you mean. Yours is better! :)